# Sending nulls in JS remoting

Tags: apex, rest-api, javascript-remoting

I am refactoring some apex code. Previously we were using REST resources and now using JS Remoting.

If an attribute is null, JS remoting won't send back any information for the attribute; whereas REST sent it back explicitly as being null

Anyone seen this before and  if so what was your work around?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you did not publish the code I'll try to experiment. Hmm. I've just createds an simple example (mostly from the JS remoting doc) of JS remoting to be able to test the `null` issue. First of all what is `null` in javascript? I think that the variable is defined but have no value. Let's try it:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="RemotingClass">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myString = 'MyFriend';

        function sayHello(helloTo) {
            RemotingClass.sayHello(helloTo, function(result, event){
                if(event.status) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="sayHello(blaa);">Say Hello</button>
    <br/>
    <div id="result">[Results]</div>

</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
global with sharing class RemotingClass {

    public RemotingClass(){
    }

    @RemoteAction
    global static String sayHello(String helloTo) {
        return 'Hello ' + helloTo;
    }
}
```

As parameter i will send `myString` to the controller. As long as this variable has a value it works just fine:

[image]

Now i remove the value: var myString <strike>= 'MyFriend'</strike>;

Trying to test it again:

[image]

Lets check whether the `helloTo` variable is declared and what gets this parameters:

```
alert('helloTo: ' + helloTo);
```

[image]

So all i need to do is to check whether parameter `helloTo` is `undefined` and if it is - manually set my variable to `null` or to the default value:

```
if(helloTo == undefined){
    helloTo = null;
}
```

Ok it works and i think this is a simplest workaround.

[image]

Comment: In JS, `undefined` is not `null`.  You can set a variable to `null` in JS.